# Azure notification hub Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azureportal

**Scenario**

I have created azure notification hub on my Visual Studio Enterprise subscription and new namespace in the azure portal according to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/create-notification-hub-portal)

**Problem**

After resources are created, I go into `overview` section of my notification hub in azure portal and I see error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

[image]

Comment: I tried to repro the issue and everything worked fine for me , didn't face the problem you are having. If the problem still is not resolved please create an support request from azure portal (support+request) for technical assistance .

Comment: I am not able to request help on my Visual Studio subscription. When I tried create notification hub on my company dev subscription everything seems to be okay. The problem occurs only on VS sub